# Discontinuity in gravitational potential

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

If you raise an object you increase it's (absolute value) potential energy.

But if you exceed an specific height suddenly the gravity can't pull over the object and it can be interpreted as the potential is turned to zero! (the intuition of potential energy is how much energy it can be released if you let the object go)

Does this mean that the potential energy's function is discontinuous? I guess not, but why? It's against my intuition!

Comment: Can you give a reference to your quote "But if you exceed an specific height suddenly the gravity can't pull over the object and it can be interpreted as the potential is turned to zero"?

Comment: I think you need to describe the shape of this object, how you are lifting it (are grabbing from the center or from the end?), what does "pull over" mean.   I can't picture the scene.

Comment: Discontinuous potential leads to a delta function force. That is a distribution and not a function, so Valter Morettis answer is still correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that many introductory physics courses say that gravitation potential energy is
$$U = mgh.$$
This is an approximate expression that only works if your mass $m$ is much lighter than the Earth and relatively close to the Earth. However, it breaks down the second you start considering more complicated situations.

For example, suppose we had an object between the Earth and the moon. Then when it's close to the moon, we have
$$U \approx m g_{\text{moon}} h_{\text{moon}}$$
and when it's close to the Earth, we have
$$U \approx m g_{\text{Earth}} h_{\text{Earth}}.$$
However, these two expressions cannot be combined consistently everywhere. In introductory courses, they sometimes gloss over this point by saying that you should only consider the nearest / most important heavy body, like the one you would fall towards if you let the object go. But that implies that the potential discontinuously changes from the first option to the second option, as you move closer from the moon to the Earth, like the moon's potential suddenly "turns off".

This problem appears because both of the expressions above are only approximate. The true potential energy is
$$U = -\frac{GM_{\text{moon}}m}{r_{\text{moon}}} - \frac{GM_{\text{Earth}}m}{r_{\text{Earth}}}$$
where the $r$'s are the distances to the center of the moon and Earth. Using some calculus, you can show that this reduces to the previous two expressions when the object is very close to either the moon or the Earth.

Comment: Thanks. But why in the first formula is multiplied by"h" while in second divided by "r" ?  How distance influence potential??

Comment: @BD. To see how this works, consider taking a graph of $-1/r$ and zooming in really close. Then the graph looks approximately equal to a line, so it is proportional to $h$. In both cases, the potential increases with distance, but the $h$ case is an approximation of a small piece of the full $-1/r$ case.

Comment: To use more math: the $h$ formula is a linearization of $-1/r$. That is, it is doing the approximation $f(r) \approx f(r_0) + (r-r_0) f'(r_0)$ and renaming $r-r_0$ to $h$.

Comment: Oh Thank you. it was exactly what i wanted. thanks for editing the post as well. Best Wishes....

Answer (score 5):

The potential is *always* defined as an integral $$U(\vec{x}) = \int^{\vec{x}}_{\vec{x}_0\:\:\Gamma} \vec{F}(\vec{r}) \cdot d\vec{r}\tag{1}$$ the path $\Gamma$ joins $\vec{x}_0$ to $\vec{x}$ and its form is irrelevent just because the vector field $\vec{F} = \vec{F}(\vec{r})$ is conservative.

It is an easy exercise to prove that the right-hand side of (1) as a function of $\vec{x}$ is always continuous if the function $\vec{F}$ is integrable (nomatter if one adopts the notion of eintegral of eithet Riemann or Lebesgue). If the function $\vec{F}$ is not integrable,  the potential does not exist at all.

Summing up: *If the potential exists, it  is necessarily continuous*.

Regarding your question, let us focus on your statement.

"But if you exceed an specific height suddenly the gravity can't pull over the object and it can be interpreted as the potential is turned to zero."

This is wrong, the correct statement would terminate like this

"...it can be interpreted as the potential is [continuously!] turned to a constant value."

since the force is the derivative of the potential and the derivative of a constant vanishes.

Comment: Not very important comment: if you allow delta function forces the potential may not be continuous. This is regularly done in QM.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your remark, I know, but my discission was restricted to classical physics and with forces described by proper functions.